# How to get distinct documents by some field in mongodb phalcon?

Tags: mongodb, phalcon

In mongo shell the query:

```
  db.collections.distinct('user_id');
```

simply gives the distinct documents.
I am working on phalcon and there is no option like

```
   Collections::distinct()
```

So how do i query distinct in phalcon. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Phalcon's answer in the forum could help: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/6832/option-for-function-distinct-phalconmvccollection

They suggest using aggregations:

```
$data = Article::aggregate(
    array(
        array(
            '$project' => array('category' => 1)
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => array('category' => '$category'),
                'id'  => array('$max' => '$_id')
            )
        )
    )
);
```